# Как в doT js пройтись по объекту?

Tags: javascript

Так работает только если это массив, а если объект то не работает.

```
'{{~it.objectMy :value}}',
    '<p>{{value}}</p>',
'{{~}}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так же как и в `javascript`

Нужно использовать конструкцию `for in`

```
{{ for(var prop in it) { }}
   <div>{{ it[prop] }}</div>
{{ } }}
```